# Can I render out different passes at one time?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-layers, render-passes

I want to render out 1 pass and not the other in my scene, but when I try to do that, blender renders out both passes at once.

Is there a way to disable some render passes so I can render single one at a time?

Comment: Disable unwanted passes in View Layer Properties > Passes ... or did I misunderstand your Q? What "both" passes are you speaking about?